# Azure Cloud Service (Classic) retrieval of client IP address

Tags: c#, azure

I have read numerous posts, blogs, questions and answers on this so I am confident that it's not a simple standard solution.

I am running an asmx style webservice within a web role and trying to retrieve the client IP address. I have multiple instances running which means the platform provides an external IP address and 'load balances' between the instances.

This all works fine but the retrieval of the client IP address through simple means like `request.UserHostAddress` returns the external port of the deployment.

Other solutions like `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` or `ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` all return null and there is nothing in the Request.ServerVariables that carries the information.

The complete list of server variables available within a request are

```
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:1584
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:text/xml; charset=utf-8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate
HTTP_EXPECT:100-continue
HTTP_HOST:myhost
HTTP_SOAPACTION:myaction
HTTP_REQUEST_CONTEXT:appId=cid-###################################
HTTP_REQUEST_ID:|################################
LOCAL_ADDR: *This is the private instance ip address as expected*
REMOTE_ADDR: *This is the external port of the service*
REMOTE_HOST: *This is the external port of the service*
```

How can this be achieved ??

Comment: Why do you need the client IP address? It's not usually considered a reliable way to identify anything much these days. You might be able to identify a rough location for the request (or at least the location where the request entered the public internet) but that's about it. Anyway you probably need to configure the load balancer to include it in a header or something when it forwards the request to your service. Whether the balancer you're using offers such a thing I don't know, you'd have to look at the docs or get support

Comment: Thanks for your interest, the why isn't quite as relevant as the how !!

The questions was specific about the hosting environment so the hope was someone was going to shed light on that that.  I am totally comfortable with the concept, just need someone from behind the scenes at MS to help or maybe someone who has solved the issue already

Answer (score 0):

Could you check ?

```
     var Request = HttpContext.Current.Request; 
     string IP = Request.Params["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] ??
     Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"].ToString() ??
     Request.Headers["Forwarded"] ??
     Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Other approach for  owin self host:

```
 if (Request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext"))
    {
    dynamic owinContext = Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];
    return owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
```

Also it might be enabled in Azure server options  https://totaluptime.com/kb/getting-the-original-client-ip-with-x-forwarded-for-in-your-code/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been through most of these options. 

The Request.Params doesn't contain the HTTP_CLIENT_IP key and the same for the two header options.

The owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress is either the same value or null (I don't have a live debugger running so hard to tell). 

Thanks again for your help, this has been a major brick-wall for me and I have now tried lots of options !!

Comment: it seems it might be set up in Azure settings.  I have added link to post

Comment: Thanks Oleg, that setting is for a different application although I totally understand the concept and agree with you that the load balancing / public facing device would have to help out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anyone that looked at this and to Oleg for his attempts.  It took a lot of digging around with remote debuggers running into an Azure deployment but eventually I found the issue.

We have an old style .asmx webservice with a WCF service in front of it with various 'inspectors' and 'routers'.  It's all pretty ugly but has worked for a long while (as I am sure many systems do!).  The logging of the remote client address has been broken for some time but the need to have it working again has become more important again recently.

The issue is related to the WCF stack behaviors and how they deal with HTTP headers as opposed to SOAP headers.  We had a version change in the Soap specification which broke the system a while back but that was fixed by setting SoapProcessingEnabled on a routing behavior to true which in essence strips all http headers and allows incompatible Soap services to communicate.

My attempts to set the header specifically in another behavior failed due to an order execution problem.

Looking forward to dropping the whole asmx / wcf stack and starting again but can't quite justify the months of development time !  Thanks again for the help